# Can an inmemory cache (CaffeineCache) survive applciation restarts?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I'm using `CaffeineCache` for some inmemory cache. Now I'm looking to persist the cache between application restarts.

Is that possible at all? Is there any framework that eg writes the cache to disk on `ApplicationCloseEvent`?

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {
    @Bean
    public CaffeineCache cache() {
        return new CaffeineCache("CACHE_NAME",
                Caffeine.newBuilder()
                        .expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                        .recordStats()
                        .build());
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing. Easiest way is to write a `@PreDestroy` method

Comment: CaffeineCache is embedded in your application or deployed on dedicated server ?

Comment: During dev+test it's an embedded in application, but in production it will be a dedicated tomcat server.